# How to determine bitwise and(&) of permutations of a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How to determine the permutations of a list and determine the value of arri&arri+1 , where & is bitwise and(&)

suppose we have a list [1,2,3] and we need to find all the permutations of this list , and then we will find is there any permutation whose arri & arri+1 is greater than 0 or not . if yes we will print only that list.

Comment: I think that this question may need to be edited for clarification. When you say array & array + 1 > 0, are you applying a bitwise & to the 3 values of each array? What would be the desired output for your example, [1,2,3]?

Comment: @Doot yes applying for three values . the desired output will be 1 3 2 there may be multiple outputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [this](https://www.codechef.com/OCT20B/problems/POSAND) question, then one possible solution would be to use backtracking. I'm sure there is a faster way to do it though.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

bool beautifulPermutations(vector<int> cur,set<int> used,int n){

    if(cur.size() == n){
        for(auto x:cur){
            cout<<x<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        return true;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if(used.find(i) == used.end()){
            if(cur.size() == 0 || (((int)cur.back() & i) > 0)){
                cur.push_back(i);
                used.insert(i);
                bool res = beautifulPermutations(cur,used,n);
                if(res)
                    return true;
                int x = cur.back();
                cur.pop_back();
                used.erase(x);
                
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t-->0){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        vector<int> v;
        set<int> s;
        if(!beautifulPermutations(v,s,n))
            cout<<-1<<endl;
    }
}
```